# trying to execute store procedure in which parameter is assign with Global Variable but unable to apply where clause to it in android studio

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio

This is store procedure to be executed

```java
String sql = "Exec Select_LoginId Where userlogin='" +emaillogin.getText() + "' 
AND Password1 = '" +passwordlogin.getText()+"'
@Log_User_Id="+GlobalVariable.StudId;'
```

Comment: You can't put a `WHERE` clause in a call to a stored procedure like that in SQL Server.  You either need to do the filtering inside the stored procedure or pull all of the data into your app and filter within the app.

Comment: That code looks like it has at several security vulnerabilities in it.... Injection and Plain text passwords to name a couple; extremely fatal flaws on their own and a apocalyptic one combined.

Comment: Use a prepared statement and move the database access layer to a service rather than connecting directly to the database from the end-user application.